# Get a real file path for a resource in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, servlets, jndi

In my web application in Tomcat 7, I get a resource in the app using `servletContext.getResource("file.xml")`. This returns an URL in the form `jndi:/localhost/app/file.xml`.

However, because I need to pass this file to a library which can only accept real file paths (it has an embedded Ruby script, I think) that URL won't do.

Is there a way to get the real file path? I know that will make the application unable to ne run from a WAR, but that's ok.

Answer (score 0):

I have a very dirty workaround:

```
        // get resource
        URL resU = servletContext.getResource("style.less");

        // get scratch dir
        File workDir = (File) servletContext.getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir");

        // copy resource to scratch file
        File newFile = new File(workDir, "style.less");
        Files.write(Resources.toByteArray(resU), newFile); // Google Guava
```

I should be able to speed this up with some caching/checksumming, but it's not pretty.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [`File#createTempFile()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

```
File file = File.createTempFile("style", ".less");
// ...
```